How to reduce time spent acquring JDBC connection?
This is a SpringBoot v2 application, by default Hikari is used for data source creation. We're trying to perform load testing with 200 users simulated firing a single endpoint for 1 minute.
During the load test, we encounter very high average response rate (eg 20 seconds ++). We believe the root cause comes from high CPU usage in DB instance, which result in much time spent during acquire of JDBC connection.
This issue only happens during load test, if we are calling the API one time, response time would be at ~2 seconds (plus minus).

Hikari Configuration
Below is the configuration done for the Hikari:
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 50
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000 
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 180000

*** The maximum-pool-size was initially 30 with idle of 10, we changed this configuration to tackle the load testing volume. It was on purpose to put it 100 maximum with 50 idle, we thought it would reduce the timespent on acquiring JDBC connection.

Load testing
The first few calls were fine with the time stats, as it fires further the time stats are going side way. Below is a comparison of First and Last time stats.
First time stats:
2024-07-31 01:11:15.698  INFO 81931 --- [masked] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    204927042 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    96128250 nanoseconds spent preparing 5 JDBC statements;
    2582852833 nanoseconds spent executing 5 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    61844917 nanoseconds spent executing 4 flushes (flushing a total of 10 entities and 2 collections);
    15162333 nanoseconds spent executing 5 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 8 entities and 8 collections)
}

Last time stats:
2024-07-31 01:12:15.678  INFO 81931 --- [masked] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    6325645250 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    104583 nanoseconds spent preparing 5 JDBC statements;
    9456613083 nanoseconds spent executing 5 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    1247332 nanoseconds spent executing 4 flushes (flushing a total of 10 entities and 2 collections);
    254583 nanoseconds spent executing 5 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 8 entities and 8 collections)
}

Question,
What seems to go wrong with our setup for acquiring JDBC connection? How can we reduce the time spent there?

"We believe the root cause comes from high CPU usage in DB instance, which result in much time spent during acquire of JDBC connection." What evidence do you have to support this hypothesis?

Hi @aled, the time stats provided should support our hypothesis. When the test begins, everything execute within expected time frame. As the load increased, CPU usage increase in DB instance, because the APIs are sort of spammed by the load test. First 10 are not finished running, next 10 and subsequent 10 request are pumped into service. Invoking the logic pulling data from database, hence result in large amount of time spent acquring JDBC connection.

That seems to be statistics at the Hibernate layer. I would look for metrics from the database, the database pool, profiling the application, cpu/memory of the application. If the database server has high CPU maybe the test is exceeding the database server resources.

IOPS and throughput looks fine from metrics, our instance 4 vcore 16gb ram,  support 500 IOPS. The only resource bursting is CPU. We actually tried upgrading the instance to 8 vcores, same result of 99% cpu consumed.  Hence we thought the issue lies at the application layer, specifically connection pool.

2582852833 nanoseconds spent executing 5 JDBC statements;, no idea what you're doing, but this is imho already an eternity.

500 IOPS is next to nothing, don't expect much performance from this box.

Indeed 2582852833 nano is unusual high, but under the hood we have multiple query running in the service within a API call. Indexing is done too, from query point of view, we see no further enhancement atm. Speaking of 500 IOPS, we do not think this is the issue, we tried upgrading to 5000 and 7500 IOPS, same result. Hence something to do with the CPU and JDBC connection acquiring.

You need profiling to see where the time is spent.

@LaurenzAlbe We're quite confident the acquiring connection is where the time spent, but it worth a shot to do profiling. Do you have any recommendation for this, eg, tools and area of focus?

That's not my area of expertise... Anyway, if it is establishing the connection, what is your problem? With a connection pool, you keep the connection open indefinitely, so you never have to open one.

@LaurenzAlbe Im taking my words back, the stats shows in post executed in local env. Moving to cloud infrastructure, we see different result. Most acquiring connection are having average of 1 - 10 seconds, some even hitting below 1 seconds. There are also few stats hitting 10+ seconds. The bottleneck now is appears in during spent executing 7 JDBC statements which at least 95% of them are ranging at 20seconds or more. Something is wrong.

A different problem then.
